# check if image exists in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

hi stack i have a quick question im attempting to see if this element exists i just need to return true or false this is the html code below i have been trying at this for hours and cant seem to figure out what i am missing any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks guys

```
<img class="js-login-available login-available" src="/assets/img/form_validation-bad.png">
```

im attempting to use this but with no luck

```
await page.$$eval('img.js-login-available login-available[src]', imgs => imgs.map(img => console.log(img.getAttribute('src'))));
```

Comment: Why are you using `$$eval` instead of just `$$`? `$$eval` runs in the context of the page -- you're logging into the browser instead of your terminal.

Comment: i honestly was going off an example i found

Comment: and even if i do this
`await page.$$('img.js-login-available login-available[src]').then(img => console.log(img))` 
it still returns empty array

Answer (score 0):

you can also solve this problem using evaluate method like this

```
let serachElemnt='img.js-login-available login-available[src]';
    let checkForElement = await page.evaluate((sel)=>{
           let elementCheck =Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(sel));
           if(elementCheck.length){
               return true
           }else return false;

    },serachElemnt);
console.log(checkForElement);
```

Please try this one.

Answer (score 0):

my resolution for this is

```
if(await page.$$eval('img.js-login-available.login-available[src]', imgs => imgs.map(img => img.getAttribute('src')).includes('/assets/img/form_validation-ok.png'))){
    console.log(names[i])
}
```